# Are empty constructors required for Json.Net deserialization in AOT devices?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I've already used Json.Net tons of times in my projects to save data, and never worried about creating parameterless constructors for my serialized classes.

Right now I am working on a project that fits this case. It uses Json.Net to serialize a few classes that do not have a parameterless constructor and it's working ok. However, I was warned by a colleague that I was lucky to have never had any problems, and that the error `ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method` could appear and crash my app at any time in iOS builds.

I've seen a lot of topics about Json.Net and Constructors or Json.Net and AOT, but nothing about Json.Net, Constructors, and AOT. At least nothing from this century.

So, my question is, should I be worried about my serialized classes with no parameterless constructors in iOS devices?

**EDIT:** my classes HAVE constructors, but they receive arguments. I would like to know if I need constructors without parameters besides them.

Comment: Probably , the problems are related with the fact that the objects Json.net will try to instantiate will be created by reflection.

Comment: @Badulake Yeah, I'm aware... I was just wondering if there is any special reason for me to never have had problems or if it was just luck indeed

Comment: Ok, I will bet for lucky

Comment: No,  you don't have to explicitly add a constructor. I haven't heard about this issue and have never ran into it on iOS. Your colleague is either confused or you probably misunderstood him. I say this because the biggest problem that causes `ExecutionEngineException` happens when Unity strips out unnecessary classes **needed** by serialization. To get around this, manually use the constructor anywhere in the project. For example, `class Test{}` then you call `new Test()` somewhere to make sure that this is not stripped out.

Comment: @Programmer Maybe I should've included in the question that the classes HAVE constructors, but they're not parameterless. I haven't made myself clear at all with "empty constructor", sorry. Going to update the question.

Comment: In that case, what your colleague said is plausible. I haven't had the issue before but I won't dismiss it because I always add parameterless constructor to my scripts. That could be true. I would wait more to see if there is anyone that have ran into this issue before

Comment: My case was a little different. I was using classes with Generics. I used Json.Net liberally throughout a Unity 2018 project without any issue, using .net standard. Until I finally built for an iOS device. And that's when it all came undone. I was using POCO's all over the place, with no constructors, because they were the same classes used on the Azure server. LUCKILY, I downloaded the Json.Net, modified the compiler conditionals, and built a Json.Net that works correctly on iOS now with AOT, targeting only 4.6 and standard. If you're not using Generics, you should be good to go.

Comment: I want to verify this. Where did you get the Json.Net version you're using?

Comment: @Programmer [JSON.NET For Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347). I did not have the time to dig deep into the subject, but I think the problem is when the type of one of the arguments of the constructor is only used via reflection as part of deserialization. In this case the AOT compiler can't detect that code needs to be generated for the type. (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html). But I'm not sure if this is the only possible problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, all you should be afraid of is the bytecode stripping, and not any facts about the number of default constructors.

The reflection part of Newtonsoft.Json to instantiate types is unavoidable, so to protect all your classes from bytecode stripping you have a couple of options.

---

Either 1: Disable bytecode stripping via a `link.xml` file. Example:

```xml
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="MyAssembly">
        <type fullname="MyAssembly.MyCSharpClass" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

I find Unity's official docs being scattered and lacking, so I rewrote a couple of docs.
Read more about how to use the `link.xml` file here: https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Fix-AOT-using-link.xml

^Based off reverse engineering the behaviour of the UnityLinker and the existing docs. For further reading, visit:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-BytecodeStripping.html

---

Option 2: Disable bytecode stripping via a `Preserve` attribute.

Adding an attribute to your class, method, field, property, event, or assembly will guarantee it not being stripped by the UnityLinker. The attribute must be named `PreserveAttribute`, so using `UnityEngine.Scripting.PreserveAttribute` or an attribute of your own called `PreserveAttribute` will yield the same result.

```cs
using UnityEngine.Scripting;

[Preserve]
public class YourTypeWithSpecialConstructor
{
    public YourTypeWithSpecialConstructor(int value1, string value2)
    {
    }
}
```

Read more about `Preserve` attribute usage: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Scripting.PreserveAttribute.html (this one I haven't rewritten :p )

---

Option 3: Using AotHelper from my release of Newtonsoft.Json for Unity.

The JSON .NET for Unity package on the Assets Store is based on Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3, however mine is currently up-to-date with Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 at the time of writing, and delivered via Unity Package Manager to more easily staying up-to-date:
https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity#readme

It includes the *Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities*.**AotHelper** class, which does not only disable bytecode stripping but also enforces compilation of certain types, something that is very beneficial when it comes to generics. Example usage:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class AotTypeEnforcer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Awake()
    {
        AotHelper.Ensure(() => {
            _ = new YourGenericTypeWithSpecialConstructor<int>(0, null);
            _ = new YourGenericTypeWithSpecialConstructor<float>(0, null);
            _ = new YourGenericTypeWithSpecialConstructor<string>(null, null);
            _ = new YourGenericTypeWithSpecialConstructor<bool>(true, null);
        });
    }
}

public class YourGenericTypeWithSpecialConstructor<T>
{
    public YourGenericTypeWithSpecialConstructor(T value1, string value2)
    {
    }
}
```

Read more about how to use the AotHelper here: https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Fix-AOT-using-AotHelper

Comment: Great answer!

One small thing, the [Preserve] attribute can not be used with a namespace

Comment: @ickydime Thank you! And good eye! I've changed it out to "assembly" as I seem to have forgotten that one.